# handling multiple useState inside conditional ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So for some reason I can't use my than one useState in my conditional ternary, but on the second example i can.

This first one has 2 useStates and seems to work.

```
    const nextAnswer = () => {
        (videoIndex === videoData.length - 1) ? 
            setVideoIndex(0):setVideoIndex(prevWord => prevWord + 1);
        setShowResults(false)
    }
```

but this one doesn't seem to want to work.

```
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false)
    const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState("Show Answer")

    const showMe = () => {
        (setShowResults === false) ? 
            setShowResults(true); setShowButton("Hide Answer"):
            setShowResults(false); setShowButton("Show Answer")
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't use a ternary for code blocks. If you need help getting the second snippet to function correctly I would suggest you look at the logic from a different perspective.

From what I can tell you want to

1. Toggle the `showResults` value
2. Conditionally render "Show/Hide Answer" based on `showResults` value

code

```
const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);

...

const showMe = () => {
  setShowResults(show => !show);
};

...

<button>{showResults ? "Hide" : "Show"} Answer</button>
```

If you *really* must use two pieces of state (even though the button text can be derived from the first) then I suggest this:

```
const showMe = () => {
  setShowResults(show => !show);
  setShowButton(setShowResults ? "Show Answer" : "Hide Answer");
}
```

Basically just trying to keep the code as **DRY** as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in your ternary, you cant run 2 statements. Just use a if statement

```
if (!showResults) {
    setShowResults(true);
    setShowButton("Hide Answer");
} else {
    setShowResults(false);
    setShowButton("Show Answer");
}
```

Comment: ah i was trying to avoid this. but i guess it cant be helped thank you!